# In what order does react native load files?

Tags: react-native, initialization, runtime

From node_modules to the app's react native code itself. Currently faced with an interesting issue where an arbitrary Settings file is being loaded and executed before a ton of the underlying files it relies on are resulting in a crash.

So I'm curious if I'm missing something. How does the react native runtime choose what to load in first? Everything from dependancies to root level code to deeply imbedded code. Does rn work by following the import statements of every file from App.js? And just flow from there? Or does it execute the files it finds recursively and check for any import statements with it?

Comment: Did you find out the load order? I'm also trying to determine this.

Comment: No, but I did manage to hack together a shim that worked for our purposes. I posted it in a related stackoverflow post

Comment: Hi @arshbot could you please link where you have posted about this? I am a bit surprised and also disappointed this does not have an answer yet.